# How to load a page completely in casperjs which requires you to manually scroll through the whole page?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Example page: http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/followers

That page gives a list of 111.5k people. **But requires me to scroll with my mouse for a long period of time to actually get the page to load completely.** How to do it automatically in casperjs?
Basically I need all the names on that page or I need to work on the page only after it has been completely loaded.
How do I do this with casperjs + phantomjs?

**Offtopic:** If there is any module in python that can do this, feel free to suggest in the comments.

Comment: I'm not very aware of the format in SO. In case I have made a mistake, please let me know, I will fix it.

Comment: Is your only goal to retreive names from the page ? If so why don't you parse the file and why do you need casperjs ?

Comment: First result when I googled `casperjs infinite scroll`: [Web scraping with CasperJS](http://www.andykelk.net/tech/web-scraping-with-casperjs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scrollTo`:

```
casper.start('http://yoursite.com', function() {
    this.scrollTo(Xvalue, Yvalue);
});
```

or even `scrollBottom`

```
casper.start('http://yoursite.com', function() {
    this.scrollBottom();
});
```

In that case you would have to wait until the javascript load the page and repeat that as many time as you need.

Comment: This does only one scroll step, not all of them.

Comment: @ArtjomB. you need to wait that the js load another part and sroll to the bottom again, and repeat that untill the page is loaded entirely

Comment: Yes, I know that. What are your suggestions for when to stop? This also has something to do with how you do this repeatedly. Hint: There's [`__utils__.getDocumentHeight`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#getdocumentheight)

Comment: @ArtjomB. I would suggest you to check if there is a new element at the end, or check if some new data is sent.

Comment: @AdamSinclair In the comments to the question, you said I can just parse the file. What do you mean by that? The page will not load completely by itself, so I won't be having all the names inside the html file. Any hints please?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I tried comparing the document height using a `while` loop. But as soon as control enters the while loop, all the `casper.something` are queued up and while is automatically checked again and so goes into an infinite loop. I can't think of a way to make it work. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: @aste123 I provided a link to a complete [solution](http://www.andykelk.net/tech/web-scraping-with-casperjs) as a comment to your question. I don't know what code you have now, so I cannot help you. You could edit your question, but I think this will invalidate the current answer.